# Array + Scalar? C

Tags: python, c

I have a program I've been toying around with and I've stumbled upon something like this:

```
unsigned char tmp[4];
...
if (mpu_write_mem(D_1_36, 2, tmp+2))
    return -1;
```

where

```
int mpu_write_mem(unsigned short mem_addr, unsigned short length,
    unsigned char *data)
```

Please forgive my ignorance, but how exactly am I adding 2 to an array? I don't quite understand. I've been trying to make a program in Python and I've been using this as reference but I'm just dumbfounded, if anyone can help with a Python equivalent for something like this, it would be really helpful too.

Answer (score 1):

You are not adding 2 to the array in this case, you are adding 2 to the memory address of tmp. In C arrays are stored as a set of *n* (length of array) sequential memory addresses. So the code tmp+2 means that you start the array at the 2nd position; a Python equivalent would be *tmp[2:]*

Also notice that the length passed to the function is 2, despite the tmp being of length 4. This is because you start 2 elements in, leaving you with only tmp[2] and tmp[3].

Comment: That makes perfect sense now! Thanks a bunch. Is that really the behavior when I add an array to a constant? Or is it because the arguments received are in the form of an address? I believe the data stored into tmp is not an address but the actual value.

Comment: The variable tmp is a pointer, this means that it holds the memory address of the data you are accessing. The data is not stored in tmp, it is stored in the memory that tmp has allocated. Try running printf("%p", tmp) and you will not see the values, but the memory address.

Comment: Is that what this does?

    tmp[0] = (unsigned char)(dmp_thresh >> 8)